# Extract a single row with only the first image from users and images table for each user

Tags: mysql

Hello I'm rather new to sql and I want to ask if there is any way to get my whole table of users listed with an extra column being the first image for each one, e.g. if one users have 5 images, instead of returning 5 rows with repeated values for user and diffrerent images I want to return only one so there is no repeated value.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  An exact answer to your question would require showing us your table structure, and ideally some sample data.  Can you share this with us?

Answer (score 1):

The SQL SELECT DISTINCT Statement
In a table, a column may contain many duplicate values; and sometimes you only want to list the different (distinct) values.

The DISTINCT keyword can be used to return only distinct (different) values.

```
SQL SELECT DISTINCT Syntax
SELECT DISTINCT column_name,column_name
FROM table_name;
```